# MySQL: Trying set a password for root, Error in SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql

This piece of code is from the **Learning MySQL and MariaDB** book:

```
mysql -u root -p -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' PASSWORD('new_pwd');"
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for th
e right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD('new_pwd')' at line 1
```

Is this book correct? Isn't this syntax old? What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with:

```
mysql -u root -p -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('new_pwd');"
```